# Is there any harm to current sessions when flushing buffer cache and shared pool?

Tags: oracle

I want to know if I run the following commands in Oracle, if it will affect any currently running queries. I plan to have someone run them in a dev environment and I haven't done this before. Not sure how long, on average, they will take either. Server is running Oracle 12c.

```
alter system flush buffer_cache;
alter system flush shared_pool;
```

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? Anyway, I had a DBA run it a few times. It ran faster than I thought and no one reported having any issues.

Comment: why do you want to run them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flush shared_pool` doesn't affect currently running queries, no. I think it would cause errors if it did. From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2017.htm#SQLRF00902):

> This statement does not clear global application context information, nor does it clear shared SQL and PL/SQL areas for items that are currently being executed.

I can't find any details about whether `flush buffer_cache` affects currently running queries. If it does, I'd guess it would just cause cache misses, and the queries would finish a bit slower than usual.

Answer (score 0):

you could just run it in your dev environment as i also usually do this to test my query performance. 
there will be no harm to your server and, agree with @kfinity, your query will finish a bit slower than usual. the next time you run the same query, it will be executed as usual.